# where is class std::out_of_range fully defined?

Tags: c++

I am searching under `/usr/include/c++` on my Ubuntu Linux. In `/usr/include/c++/stdexcept`, I found this:

```
class out_of_range : public logic_error
{
public:
    explicit out_of_range(const string& __arg);
 };
```

But I can't find anywhere the definition of `out_of_range()` constructors.

Also when the STL throws an `out_of_range()` exception, it uses (example taken from `stl_vector.h`):

```
__throw_out_of_range(__N("vector::_M_range_check"));
```

And, the only thing I can find for `__throw_out_of_range()` is:

```
void __throw_out_of_range(const char*) __attribute__((__noreturn__));
```

Can you kindly point me to where the definitions of the `out_of_range` class?

Comment: Have you looked at [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range)?

Comment: +1 Good question. Want to know that, too.

Comment: I've found it for you on github mirror of gcc:

<https://github.com/mirrors/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/c%2B%2B98/stdexcept.cc>, line 60.

Answer (score 3):

They're probably defined in `libstdc++`. You can get the source code on the [GCC website](http://gcc.gnu.org/libstdc++/). On Ubuntu distros, you just have the library installed (`libstdc++.so`), not the source code. The stuff you found are just the declarations, not the definitions.

Answer (score 1):

`std::out_of_range` is fully defined in **§19.2.5 Class `out_of_range` [out.of.range]** of the C++11 standard.

Answer (score 0):

Those are in `libstdc++` which is built as part of `gcc`.  You can download `gcc-core-X.Y.Z.tar.bz2` and find it there.

Answer (score 0):

here you go

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-3.4/stdexcept_8cc-source.html

keep in mind that libstdc++ is no longer distributed as a single library, but the source of the library is actually bundled with gcc, so to download libstdc++ you have to download gcc.